# Performing a computation on subset using R and dplyr

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

I have a df of 4 columns - c("Observation.ID", "Event.Type", "Property.Damage", "Magnitude").

Magnitude values signify whether property damage is given in thousands, millions, or billions of dollars ("K","M","B").

I want to normalize Property.Damage, so I need to separately compute for the 3 groups:

```
update df set Property.Damage=(Property.Damage*n) where Magnitude='K'
```

In dplyr, I understand how to split on class, add the recomputed property damage, combine, then summarize. Surely it's possible to do this more simply, a la SQL?

Edit: I went with data.table because it feels quick/easy compared to base. E.g.:

```
setkey(df1, Magnitude)
df1["K", PROPDMG := PROPDMG*1e3]
df1["M", PROPDMG := PROPDMG*1e6]
df1["B", PROPDMG := PROPDMG*1e7]
```

Comment: Refined my question a bit.

Answer (score 3):

You may be better off just making a look up table and merging this back in before doing the multiplication. Something like:

```
df <- data.frame(propdmg=1:6, magnitude=rep(c("K","M","B"),each=2))
df

#  propdmg magnitude
#1       1         K
#2       2         K
#3       3         M
#4       4         M
#5       5         B
#6       6         B

lkup <- data.frame(magnitude=c("K","M","B"),mult=c(1e3,1e6,1e7))
left_join(df, lkup) %>% mutate(result=propdmg * mult, mult=NULL)

#Joining by: "magnitude"
#  propdmg magnitude result
#1       1         K  1e+03
#2       2         K  2e+03
#3       3         M  3e+06
#4       4         M  4e+06
#5       5         B  5e+07
#6       6         B  6e+07
```

The direct equivalent in base R would be:

```
transform(merge(df, lkup), result=mult * propdmg, mult=NULL)
```

Answer (score 3):

I found that data.table was the most appealing approach. In fact, this has switched me from dplyr to data.table for split/apply/combine. Although it appears `base R` makes for the fewest keystrokes - I find data.table's `i,j, := is` less wonky parenthetically.

```
setkey(df1, Magnitude)
df1["K", PROPDMG := PROPDMG*1e3]
df1["M", PROPDMG := PROPDMG*1e6]
df1["B", PROPDMG := PROPDMG*1e7]
```

---

Alternatively, we can create another *data.table* as follows:

```
df2 = data.table(Magnitude = c("K", "M", "B"), mult = c(1e3, 1e6, 1e9))
```

and then perform an *update* while joining as follows:

```
df1[df2, PROPDMG := PROPDMG*mult, by=.EACHI, on="Magnitude"]
```

`on=` allows to perform binary search based subsets/joins without having to set keys. `by=.EACHI` evaluates expression in `j` for *each row* in `df2`.

Answer (score 1):

We could use `base R` to do this

```
transform(df1, Property.Damage = Property.Damage * setNames(c(1e3, 
            1e6, 1e9), c("K", "M", "B"))[Magnitude])
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(Observation.ID = 1:5, Event.Type = LETTERS[1:5], 
     Property.Damage = c(1, 5, 3, 4, 7), 
     Magnitude = c("K", "M", "K", "B", "M"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks, that is seemingly the fewest keystrokes.